# gemfirexd client log not logging

Tags: gemfire, snappydata

I am running this from ubuntu.  The Gemfire client log is not logging.  Is there something incorrect in my syntax or property settings?

```
java -jar sample-snappydata-sensor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
-Dgemfirexd.debug.true=TraceClientStatementMillis,TraceClientConn,TraceClientHA 
-Dgemfirexd.client.log-file=snappydata-client.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving full path for log-file e.g. /home/.../snappydata-client.log and see if it shows up there.

Alternatively, you can also set the log-file in connection settings (and try full path). For example:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:snappydata://.../;log-file=...")
```

Comment: That worked. A file is created now.  But, it is empty.  Is there a similar Driver setting for the 'TraceClientStatementMillis,TraceClientConn,TraceClientHA' field I need to pass as well?

Comment: So for some reason the "-D" properties are not being passed?

There is no driver setting but there is a system procedure: SYS.SET_TRACE_FLAG("TraceClientStatementMillis", 1).

Alternatively you can try calling "System.setProperty()" in the program in a static block or something before SnappyData classes are initialized.

Comment: By system procedure I mean executed as standard SQL on JDBC statement. Use single quotes for SQL strings: statement.execute("call SYS.SET_TRACE_FLAG('TraceClientStatementMillis', 1)). Can be done only on a JDBC connection so this will not give logs prior to the system call.

Answer (score 0):

The settings look correct. Can you check if snappydata-client.log is created?

Comment: There is no log in the current directory where I started Spring Boot from the -jar.  Where else should I look?